Converting 1H OHLC Data to 3H OHLC Data using Pandas Dataframe
I have 1hr data in df from yfinance. I need to convert that data into 3h interval.
Sample Code:
pip install yfinance
import yfinance as yf
ticker_symbol = '^NSEI'  # Nifty index symbol on Yahoo Finance
df = yf.download(ticker_symbol, start='2023-01-01', end='2024-01-01',interval='1h')
df_new = df.resample("3H").mean()

df Output:
                                Open             High            Low          Close    Adj Close    Volume
Datetime                        
2023-01-02 09:15:00+05:30   18131.699219    18172.949219    18087.550781    18162.900391    18162.900391    0
2023-01-02 10:15:00+05:30   18159.400391    18199.300781    18155.400391    18186.500000    18186.500000    0
2023-01-02 11:15:00+05:30   18186.099609    18192.949219    18170.500000    18192.050781    18192.050781    0
2023-01-02 12:15:00+05:30   18190.650391    18197.300781    18153.900391    18182.349609    18182.349609    0
2023-01-02 13:15:00+05:30   18182.250000    18193.449219    18157.949219    18170.099609    18170.099609    0
2023-01-02 14:15:00+05:30   18169.949219    18205.099609    18123.199219    18193.050781    18193.050781    0
2023-01-02 15:15:00+05:30   18192.099609    18215.099609    18192.099609    18208.949219    18208.949219    0
2023-01-03 09:15:00+05:30   18163.199219    18232.500000    18149.949219    18230.250000    18230.250000    0
2023-01-03 10:15:00+05:30   18230.099609    18238.949219    18215.949219    18231.250000    18231.250000    0
2023-01-03 11:15:00+05:30   18231.099609    18240.400391    18195.800781    18198.199219    18198.199219    0
2023-01-03 12:15:00+05:30   18198.349609    18198.949219    18162.500000    18184.550781    18184.550781    0                               

Current Output: df_new
                               Open             High            Low            Close    Adj Close   Volume
Datetime                        
2023-01-02 09:00:00+05:30   18159.066406    18188.399740    18137.817057    18180.483724    18180.483724    0.0
2023-01-02 12:00:00+05:30   18180.949870    18198.616536    18145.016276    18181.833333    18181.833333    0.0
2023-01-02 15:00:00+05:30   18192.099609    18215.099609    18192.099609    18208.949219    18208.949219    0.0
2023-01-02 18:00:00+05:30   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2023-01-02 21:00:00+05:30   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2023-01-03 00:00:00+05:30   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

Expected Output:
                                 Open            High            Low            Close   Adj Close   Volume
Datetime                        
2023-01-02 09:15:00+05:30   18131.699219    18199.300781    18087.550781    18192.050781    18192.050781    0.0
2023-01-02 12:15:00+05:30   18190.650391    18205.099609    18123.199219    18193.050781    18193.050781    0.0
2023-01-02 15:15:00+05:30   18192.099609    18215.099609    18192.099609    18208.949219    18208.949219    0.0
2023-01-03 09:15:00+05:30   18163.199219    18240.400391    18149.949219    18198.199219    18198.199219    0


df_new = df.resample("3H").mean().dropna(how='all')

df_resampled = nifty_data.resample('3H').agg({
    'Open': 'first',
    'High': 'max',
    'Low': 'min',
    'Close': 'last',
    'Adj Close': 'last', 
    'Volume': 'sum'
})

# Optional: Drop rows with all NaN values if any
df_resampled.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)

# Print the result
df_resampled

Output:
                               Open            High             Low         Close Adj Close Volume
Datetime                        
2023-01-02 09:00:00+05:30   18131.699219    18199.300781    18087.550781    18192.050781    18192.050781    0
2023-01-02 12:00:00+05:30   18190.650391    18205.099609    18123.199219    18193.050781    18193.050781    0
2023-01-02 15:00:00+05:30   18192.099609    18215.099609    18192.099609    18208.949219    18208.949219    0

Ref Link: https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/issues/6042#issuecomment-547632305
